# Are excessive selfies a "cry for help" from "sexually abandoned" people?

Tags: sexuality

I just read an article in the Spanish newspaper [Hoy](http://hoy.com.do/fanatica-de-las-selfies-un-estudio-asegura-que-te-falta-sexo/) (not a great source for scientific knowledge) and that says (translated by me):

> Are you a fan of selfies? Well, a study made by a Dutch researcher, Christyntjes Van Gallagher, from Wageninge University, discovered that excessive selfies are a cry for help from people who feel sexually abandoned (...)

According to the article, the study is called: "Het van fotograferen ontbering en eenzaamheid", but sadly, I haven't been able to find a well respected source (or at least, the study per se).

So, does this study actually exist? or, at least, is it true what it's been claimed?

Comment: Just spent three times as long as I normally would to find the paper - can't find the article or the researcher or anyone with the name "Christyntjes". At least the university exists: (http://www.wageningenur.nl/)

Comment: Strange things about this: 1. A [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Christyntjes+Van+Gallagher) for Christyntjes Van Gallagher yields results in... spanish; 2. [NCBI database](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=selfie) has no study conducted on selfies 3. [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=selfie) yields [incredibly scientific](http://www.xlcr.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Dark-undercurrents-of-teenage-girls.pdf) papers :-).

Comment: @Cornelius: re: 1. I assume a Spanish reporter has mangled the Dutch scientists name (and, most likely, the science), and the rest are copy-paste journalism.

Comment: I am not actually fluent in Dutch, but the title ought to be "Het fotograferen van ontbering en eenzaamheid". Even here, Google finds mostly Spanish articles about this alleged research publication. Some articles quotes "Galagher" (with one l) as the surname. There are some publications from Wageningen UR written by some "Gallagher, C.", but the subjects are food and nutrition research.